# Figure and caption are not working together

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

I have trouble with figure in latex. I would like to put the caption at the bottom of figure. But result is always like that.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{mypicture.eps}
\caption{what problem with it.}
\label{fig:fairness}
\end{figure}
```

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[t] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{mypicture.eps} 
\caption{what problem with it.} 
\label{fig:fairness} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[My picture .eps is attached here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/20um665qc8cqlzc/mypicture.eps?dl=0)

Comment: Could you extend your code to a MWE that includes the packages you load?

Comment: My example is simple. I just want to test. The last time when I put the figure in my project, it works fined.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{mypicture.eps}
\caption{what problem with it.}
\label{fig:fairness}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Comment: Your MWE code compiles fine if the `demo` option is passed to `graphicx` (since we don't have the file `mypicture.eps`). How was the eps file created?

Comment: The picture seems to indicate that the EPS file has a bad bounding box.

Comment: This looks like a gnuplot graphics file. Normally, those `.eps` files are of high quality and their bounding box is correct

Comment: Thanks all! I also think the problem is about bounding box. But I dont have the original picture, just a EPS file. So, using trim is possible?

Comment: You are loading graphicx twice and graphics once. graphicx loads graphics, so the three commands can be replaced by \usepackage{graphicx}.

Comment: Could you post the .eps file?

Comment: I attached my .eps file on the top. I am sure that the problem is about a bad bounding box. But I have not found solution yet. I tried to fix with "trim" but it is still not working. So, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not at a pc so cannot test. You can check the boundingbox by wrapping `\fbox{...} ` around the entire `\includegraphics... ` a box will then show the scaled boundingbox as latex sees it. Exactly how are you compiling?

Comment: Maybe you are viewing a DVI file with a viewer, which only provides rudimentary support for EPS files. Then convert to PDF and review the file with a PDF viewer.

Comment: HeikoOberdiek:  I know exactly what is going on. I mean I already set Latex -  DVI -PDF. What I see is from PDF.
daleif: I use \fbox{} and find that my picture is out of box.
I use Texniccenter to compile. Nothing is different

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you very much for spending time with me. Finally, I fixed this problem with "trim".

Comment: @TungDoan - If you solved it, you can consider posting your solution as an answer.